# How to fetch .csv files files attached in emails

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysql

I have to work on this task where i'll have to fetch .csv files attached in email and insert it into my database using php. Is there any way I can get this done, please help me if you have any idea regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEAR::Mail_mimeDecode](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_mimeDecode/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to know the logic...so that I can get it done. I have no idea on how i can access my mail using php and fetch the attached files

Comment: did you do any research about accessing email with PHP?